# SQL - Como trazer apenas as linhas (ID e Data/hora) com menos de 1 hora

Tags: sql, sql-server, data

Estou precisando da seguinte ajuda:

Estou com uma tabela que preciso comparar as transações com o mesmo ID, mas apenas trazer essas linhas de ID que tiverem a transação anterior com o mesmo ID com menos de 1h.

Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ai traz as linhas com menos de 1h entre elas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você não informou qual SGBD está utilizando portanto verifique se ele disponibiliza "window functions" que atenderá a sua ncessidade.

Comment: estou utilizando SQL Server

Comment: qual versão do SQL Server você está utilizando? As linhas são retornadas em ordem decrescente de data/hora e a primeira do ID sempre deve ser retornada?

Comment: 2013, sim e sim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando a função Lag para obter o valor de uma coluna de uma linha anterior:

```
select t.* 
from Tabela as t
where 
    datediff
        (minute, 
         lag(DataHora, 1, t.DataHora) 
             over(partition by id_omega order by DataHora desc), 
         t.DataHOra) < 60
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Pra dar 100% certo eu coloquei o que seria where no select e tirei o t. de tudo. Obrigado!